# What kind of analysis can I make in order to understand which variable impact the most my result?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, exploratory-data-analysis

Here's the thing, I have data from my products in a dataset just like this:

```
id        product        city            sold
A00       pd_1           Chicago         1
A01       pd_3           Miami           1
A02       pd_2           Seattle         0
A03       pd_7           Boston          1
A04       pd_8           Boston          0
A05       pd_2           Nashville       0
A05       pd_7           Nashville       0
```

The last variable is a dummy which tells you if the product was sold (1) or not (0). IDs are unique, product and city no.
I want to know where is my problem, in the type of product or in the city.
Since I may be selling things in a small city with less people to buy (or the product may not be suitable to people there), city may be impacting my sales. However, the product may also not be interesting.

So, how can I analyse that? Any thoughts and recommendations?

At first, I thought a logistic regression could help me here. But there are too many cities and products. Transforming them in dummy variables would not work.

So, what can I do here? I know it's kind of a vague issue, but since I've been thinking about this a lot and I have no clue at all, I would really appreciate any idea.

Comment: All "id" and "product" are unique? So analysis can only be done for "city" vs "sold"?

Comment: Hi @KaPy3141, id is unique, product no. I guess I need to clarify that

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume your dataset also has descriptive variables of the products and cities? You should have, for each city, variables related to demographics and population, for example ratio males/females, distribution across age groups, education level, etc etc (there may be more specific variables that make sense to add that I can't 'guess' because I don't know what are your products); for each product, you should have variables descriptive of the product (I am not going to give suggestions of examples of these variables, as those require prior knowledge of the product and, therefore, you have to be the one to define them.

Then, you can train a model that allows you to analyze the relationship / weight of each variable to the output (the two models I've used that allow you to do this are Random Forest and Partial Least Squares, but I'm sure there are many more).

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to simple compare different products that were sold in the same respective city (or cities) and different cities in their common products, that were sold in all cities you want to compare at once.

Doing more than that needs active assumptions that you need to take and justify. Obviously you can try to fit your binary 'sold' data by a function or operator of (product,city) but if you don't exactly know what you are doing, you can't interpret the result anyways.

So is the second approach what you aim for?

Comment: I guess the second approach was what I was thinking about. But the first one could be useful. The problem is that I have dozens of products, it would have to be a sample